# openmp broken by visual studio c++ optimization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openmp

I've been using OpenMP with Visual Studio 2010 for quite some time by now, but today I've encountered yet another baffling quirk of VS. After cutting off all the possible suspects, I was left with the program below.
It simply counts in a cycle and sometimes makes some calculation and churns out counters.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "omp.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;
    double c = 3, mean_tau = 1, r_w = 1, weights = 1, r0 = 1, tau = 1, sq_tau = 1, 
        r_sw = 1;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3) shared(count)
    {
        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        int pers_count = 0;
        std::string someline;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            pers_count++;
#pragma omp critical
            {
                count++;
                if ((count%10000 == 0))
                {

                    sq_tau = (r_sw / weights) * pow( 1/ r0 * tau, 2);
                    std::cout << count << " " << pers_count << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I compile it with optimisation disabled (/Od), it works just as it should, spitting out their shared counter alongside with its private counter (which is roughly three times smaller), something along the lines of

```
10000 3890
20000 6523
...
300000 100000
```

If I turn on the optimisation (I tried all options, but for clarity's sake let's say /O2), however, for some reason the shared count seems to become private, as I start getting something like

```
10000 10000
10000 10000
10000 10000
...
60000 60000
50000 50000
...
100000 100000
```

And now that I encountered this quirk, somehow everything that was working before is rebuilt into incorrect version even if I don't change a thing. What could be the cause of this and what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I can reproduce with VS2010. Runs correctly in VS2012 and VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the shared `count` is behaving this way. I can provide a workaround (assuming you only use atomic operations on the shared variable):

```
#pragma omp critical
    {
#pragma omp atomic
        count++;
        if ((count%10000 == 0))
        {

            sq_tau = (r_sw / weights) * pow( 1/ r0 * tau, 2);
            std::cout << count << " " << pers_count << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, atomic fixes this particular problem, but so does commenting out the _std::string someline;_ line. This is merely a condensed example, in the actual code using pragma atomic with atomic operations fixed **some**, but this only made it harder to notice the eventual data corruption. Anyways, thanks for confirming it's not just me using VS wrong, I just chose to switch to VS2012.